# Adding Controls to Theme Customizer If Certain Page Template is Active

Tags: conditional-tags, theme-customizer

How to Conditionally add controls on Theme Customizer panel. Conditional like `is_page()` or `is_page_template()` obviously does/will not work because the page is being shown is `customize.php`.

### Code Example

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_theme_customize_register', 11 );

function my_theme_customize_register($wp_customize){
    if( is_page_template('my-template.php'){
        // add special control
    }
}
```

**Another observation** is, customization setting control panel does not refresh when we switch to pages. It uses ajax to load theme preview. So, I guess theme customizer did not intend to use for post/page specific settings. So, am I hitting a dead end?

Comment: Page/Post Specific customization will soon be [available with WP 4.0](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/07/08/customizer-improvements-in-4-0/). Look at [WP Customize Post](https://github.com/x-team/wp-customize-posts). It is a great starting point.