# Associate the "add_rewrite_endpoint" and "$_GET"

Tags: rewrite-rules, endpoints

I have an i18n class.

The class find lang tag. For example: `"?lang=en"`

And i want it work with subdir. For example: `eg.com/en` and `eg.com/hello-world/en`

For this i am using: `add_rewrite_endpoint`

```
function lang_add_endpoints(){
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    add_rewrite_endpoint('en', EP_ALL);
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
} 
add_action('init', 'lang_add_endpoints');
```

But the class work with `lang` tag. For this i am using: `add_rewrite_rule`

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    add_rewrite_rule('^en/?', 'index.php?lang=en', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

But i tested `$_GET['lang']`don't set.

So i want, all: page, post, archive and home pages support "/en/" subdir. And this fire `$_GET["lang"] = "en"`

---

Now i solve with:

```
function lang_add_endpoints(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint('lang', EP_ALL);
} 
add_action('init', 'lang_add_endpoints');
```

and

```
if(get_query_var('lang')) $_GET["lang"] = get_query_var('lang');
```

`eg.com/anypost/lang/en` this work now. But i want to remove lang slug `/lang/`

`eg.com/anypost/en` this how to fire `$_GET["lang"] = "en"` i try: `get_query_var('en')` don't set, because `/en/` haven't a value.

I think `if(isset(get_query_var('en')))` like this solve it.

Comment: Try `get_query_var( 'lang' )`. WordPress removes any query args it recognises from `$_GET` and puts them in 'query vars'. Also, don't flush rewrite rules on `init`. Either do it manually by going to Settings > Permalinks, or do it _once_. See [this note](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/#comment-2645) as an example.

Comment: @JacobPeattie i am refresh the ask. Please read it.

Comment: If you’re using an endpoint, just adding ‘en’ and using `get_query_var( 'en' )` would be the way to do it. You wouldn’t use ‘lang’.

Comment: @JacobPeattie ty, but i am how to detect `eg.com/en/` or `eg.com/` because  `/en/-null-` don't fire `the get_query_var('en')` for this i want `isset()` but i try `isset` not work with functions.

Comment: You can try `array_key_exists( 'en', $wp_query->query_vars )` to detect an empty endpoint.

Comment: You can set the default value to `false` using the second argument, then you can check if it's actually false and not just `''`: `if ( get_query_var( 'en', false ) !== false )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters added using `add_rewrite_endpoint()` are available using `get_query_var()`.

So if you register `/en/` as an endpoint:

```
function wpse_318560_en_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint('en', EP_ALL);
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_318560_en_endpoint' );
```

And don't flush rewrite rules on `init`. Rewrite rules only need to be flushed once. See [this note](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/#comment-2645) in the developer docs for a way to properly flush rewrite rules programmatically.

Then you can use [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) to check if the endpoint is present.

One important thing to note is that `get_query_var` returns the value of the query var. When adding an endpoint, the 'value' of the endpoint is whatever comes after the `/en/` in the URL. In your use-case this will be an empty string: `''`. The thing to be careful of is that the default value of `get_query_var()` when `/en/` is missing is *also* `''`.

So to properly check if `/en/` is set in the URL, you need to use the 2nd argument of `get_query_var()` to change the default value to `false`:

```
// example.com/page/
get_query_var( 'en' );        // ''
get_query_var( 'en', false ); // false

// example.com/page/en/
get_query_var( 'en' );        // ''
get_query_var( 'en', false ); // ''
```

So to properly check for `/en/` you need to do it like this:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'en', false ) !== false ) {

}
```

Comment: what's wpse_318560 ? is this name a deeper sense?

Comment: See my comment here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300815/how-to-add-theme-customizer-control-to-specific-page#comment444964_300863